# How is a server generated primary key returned to the RIA client

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I'm using a loose coupling between presentation and my domain entites.  When the client calls SubmitChanges it correctly calls my insert method on the server, passing up the "to-be-added" presentation model instance.

The server side code will does the insert including generating a primary key.  But how am I to pass this primary key back to the client?

Update:
In response to comment let me give more detail: Yes, I'm using RIA Service, but the entities that the RIA Services service exchanges with the client are not the same as the entities that go to the database.  Therefore I can't rest on some behind the scenes magic at the server side.  My insert method signature looks like so:

```
public void InsertPerson(PersonInfo source)
{


}
```

The PersonInfo class looks like this:

```
public class PersonInfo
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    // you get the point
}
```

During the process of inserting the primary key is determined (server side)  The client side obviously needs this information, how does it get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@GarethOwen Even with POCO objects the id values as long as they are set to the POCO object within the service they should be updated on the client. Normally though you don't set the POCO ID if you aren't using a Guid. So if you are using an int for an ID then you can do it this way.

```
public void InsertPOCO(POCOObj POCO)
{
   RealObj x = new RealObj();

   x.Info = ...(information)...;

   this.DataContext.RealObjs.InsertOnSubmit(RealObj);

   this.DataContext.SubmitChanges();

   // Once the Submit Changes has run, the x object will then have an id value associated with it, and you can now assign the ID value of the POCO Object
   POCO.Id = x.Id;
}
```

And then you don't have to re-query the domain service for the Id value.

Comment: In fact we do use GUID as primary key values.

Answer (score 0):

From your tags I assume you are using RIA Services. If you've mapped your entities including the Ids of the tables, you just get the inserted identity back in the same object on the client side.

Like in the following example code <sub>(copied from other question here on SO):</sub>

```
MyEntity ent = new MyEntity(); //entity that has Id, mapped 
//from primary key (Identity) from data base

MyDataContext.MyEntities.Add(ent);
MyDataContext.SubmitChanges(op => { 
  if (!op.HasError) MessageBox.Show(ent.Id.ToString()); 
});
```

Comment: I've updated my question providing greater detail on what's going on and why your answer falls short in my particular case.

Comment: Ok clear, so you do a client side mapping of the RIA services objects to custom data objects, then you send these custom data objects back to the ria service to insert? Do you use Entity Framework to store this custom class PersonInfo? Then you could return the identity in the insert method as f.i. a regular int and do the mapping of the custom class yourself on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

Rody is correct, as long as you set the Id value of your PersonalInfo object on the server side that object will then be updated on the client upon completion of the submit changes. Are you attempting to access the Id value outside of the submit changes completed callback? I'm assuming this is an asyncronous request?

Comment: Since the InsertPersonInfo function returns void, how does the ID value get back to the client?

Comment: The update, insert, and delete methods do return voids, but the actual object is passed by reference to the domain service since that is how c# deals with variables in the first place. So any changes that effect the variable on the server side are passed back to the client by reference through the domain service connection. So even though the insert, update, and delete methods are returning voids the values are still changing and updating on the client side.

Comment: @devnew,  if you would put your command as an answer I would certainly make it as good.  I have verified that RIA service between client and server is doing exactly what you describe.  In my defence I will say that pass by reference over the wire is not exactly intuitive, -- but I like it ;)

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar loosely coupled architecture. Our DomainService works with POCOs designed specifically for the server-client communication - so our persistence layer is well hidden from our clients (Silverlight and HTML5).

<strike>As far as I know, the server side generated ID is not sent back to the client. We make another query to get the objects again.</strike>

I'd be grateful to know if this is unnecessary.

See other answers - it is possible - I learnt something with this question and can improve our code because of it.